# How to estimate the norm of Jacobi fields or to compute $\langle J(0),J'(0)\rangle$

Tags: riemannian-geometry

There is a classical formula based on Taylor series for the square norm of a Jacobi field $J$ with $J(0) = 0$ along a geodesic on a Riemannian manifold $M$. I am interested on a possible estimate for the square norm of a Jacobi field $J$ such that $J(0) = X\neq 0$. Or simply, it would be nice to understand the relation between $J(0)$ and $J'(0)$. Can we guarantee under any assumption that $\langle J(0),J'(0)\rangle \neq 0$?

Comment: No you can‘t guarantee that, since vor any $v,w \in T_pM$ there exists a Jacobi field $J$ with $J(0)=v$ and $J‘(0)=w$.

Comment: @FriederJäckel, in fact I meant "some assumption" in the sense that "is this true in any case?", not "any" in the sense "every". But now I realized that the Jacobi field is determined by the initial condition, so we can choose $J$ satisfying the desired requirement.